# How to convert channel.tx artifact into json in hyper ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was playing around hyper ledger fabric and understood how to convert genesis.pb artifact into a genesis.json file using configtxlator tool provided by hyper ledger but i am not able to convert channel.tx artifact into its corresponding JSON. I am using the following command.

configtxlator proto_decode --input channel.tx  --type common.Message > channel.json

Note: I am executing this command in CLI client provided by hyper ledger fabric.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use `configtxgen` to do this:

`configtxgen --inspectChannelCreateTx channel.tx`

Comment: Hi it worked, and I had found out a solution through configtxlator tool, following command will work  configtxlator proto_decode --input channel.tx --type common.Envelope > channel.json

Answer (score 0):

Use protolator tool from hyperledger bin folder

- mychannel.tx is a binary file
- One can decode this file using protolator
  Commands:

**Step1**: GOTO fabricsamples/bin ./configtxlator start

**Step2**: GOTO mychannel.tx file location then issue below command

> curl -X POST --data-binary @mychannel.tx
>   http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/decode/common.Envelope >
>   mychannel.json

The results of decoding the file mychannel.tx which is a **common.Envelope** produced by the configtxgen tool contains a common.ConfigUpdate object. This object has the name "**config_update**" within the "payload.data" JSON object.

This is the object that is needed as the source of the template to be used for creating new channels. The common.ConfigUpdate is the object that will be signed by all organizations and submitted to the orderer to create a new channel.

mychannel.tx contains read/write set of mychannel

Result:

> {   "channel_id": "mychannel",   "read_set": {
>       "groups": {
>         "Application": {
>           "groups": {
>             "Org1MSP": {}
>           }
>         }
>       },
>       "values": {
>         "Consortium": {
>           "value": {
>             "name": "SampleConsortium"
>           }
>         }
>       }   },   "write_set": {
>       "groups": {
>         "Application": {
>           "groups": {
>             "Org1MSP": {}
>           },
>           "mod_policy": "Admins",
>           "policies": {
>             "Admins": {
>               "policy": {
>                 "type": 3,
>                 "value": {
>                   "rule": "MAJORITY",
>                   "sub_policy": "Admins"
>                 }
>               }
>             },
>             "Readers": {
>               "policy": {
>                 "type": 3,
>                 "value": {
>                   "sub_policy": "Readers"
>                 }
>               }
>             },
>             "Writers": {
>               "policy": {
>                 "type": 3,
>                 "value": {
>                   "sub_policy": "Writers"
>                 }
>               }
>             }
>           },
>           "version": "1"
>         }
>       },
>       "values": {
>         "Consortium": {
>           "value": {
>             "name": "SampleConsortium"
>           }
>         }
>       }   } }